# dlib object detector for dog face detection - need advice on improving recall

Tags: dlib

I'm trying to train a dog face detector with dlib's hog pyramid detector.
I used Columbia dogs dataset: ftp://ftp.umiacs.umd.edu/pub/kanazawa/CU_Dogs.zip

At first I would get a recall of 0%, but by increasing C value I managed to increase it to 65% on training set and 45% on testing set. After certain point increasing C value stopped helping (1000+) and would only slow down training.

Could you give any advice on how I could improve recall to a descent recall quality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dog face detection with dlib - need advice on improving recal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398122/dog-face-detection-with-dlib-need-advice-on-improving-recal)